# Nodejs - return a subset of a list such that they contain values in the other list

Tags: node.js

So suppose there are two lists

```
var parsedList = ['a','b','c','d']
var originalList = ['a#','c#','h#']
```

And I would like to return a subset of originalList which contains values in the parsedList. (e.g. `['a#','c#']` as 'a' and 'c' is in the parsedList) Is there a simple and elegant way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is very straightforward  and elegant, first you loop over your `originalList`
and then for each element in that array, you want to check if `parsedList` includes it or not, and you can do that with `parseList.includes()`

```js
    var parsedList = ['a','b','c','d']
    var originalList = ['a','c','h']
    let newArr = []

    originalList.forEach(element => {
        if (parsedList.includes(element)){
            newArr.push(element)
        }
    })
    console.log(newArr) // ['a', 'c']
```

do you want something like that or you want to edit`originalList` ?
in case you want it in the same array

```
 originalList = originalList.filter(element => {
        return parsedList.includes(element)
    })
    console.log(originalList) // ['a', 'c']
```